# The type or namespace name 'Rigidbody2d' could not be found error in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a simple jump script in unity2d. (I am very new to c#) and its saying that Rigidbody2d cannot be found. I have proper spelling and caps.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
  float jump;
  private Rigidbody2d rb;
  public float jumpHeight;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2d>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    jump = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode=Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, jump * jumpHeight);
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

> I have proper spelling and caps

C# is case sensitive, it's [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html).